# Alfresco Messages conventions

Tags: properties, naming-conventions, alfresco

I know Alfresco stores messages and i18n labels for the UI in ".properties" files, 
I would like to know what are the Alfresco conventions to write those files

How it is better to write those key?
It is correct to write `form.form-id.title=myTitle` or should I use another convention?
Do you use another prefix like the namespace (`myc.form.form-id.title=myTitle`)

Thanks to all

Comment: Do you want the keys to be used by your own code only, or are you expecting Alfresco to pickup these automatically for custom forms / components / etc?

Comment: essentially for my code, I know I can use whatever sintax I choose, but I was asking for an official guide to follow to adopt as a standard. I have this problem because many people works in the same project, and we use a different approach for naming.
By the way, custom forms/components /etc is my own code. I don't understand the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, if you want to set labels in properties files for a custom form, you have to keep Alfresco standards. See comments in **tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension/share-config-custom.xml** :

> If a type has been specified without a title element in the content model, or you need to support multiple languages, then an i18n file is needed on the Repo AMP/JAR extension side for the type to be visible when creating rules:
>
> custom_customModel.type.custom_mytype.title=My SubType
>
> Used by the "Change Type" action. For the type to have a localised label add relevant i18n string(s) in a Share AMP/JAR extension:
>
> type.custom_mytype=My SubType

But if you define your own properties in custom Java code and spring beans, maybe could you keep choose the most comprehensive name for a user or admin sys which will have to configure your properties.
To answer to your question, I don't know any standard for these new properties.

Hope it helps